# call two actions when click on one button Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

How to make one button call two different actions as I have print button that is supposed to call 2 different actions from the same controller to print two different pages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in calling two actions at once, if you want to print two pages, user must make two requests, and by that he must have two windows open, so this is done by opening a second window to the desired URL and sending the user to the other action in his current window.

In pure JavaScript:

```
window.open("http://domain.com/controller/action_one");
window.location = "http://domain.com/controller/action_two";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the button call one controller function, call the other function from the first.

```
echo form_open('myForm', '/myFunction');
echo form_submit();
```

Controller:

```
 function myFunction() {
    //do stuff;
    $this->mySecondFunction();
 }


 function mySecondFunction() {
    do more stuff;
 }
```